# Grails - Register SessionListener as a Spring Bean

Tags: grails, spring-security

Is it possible to register a Session Listener (implementation of HttpSessionListener) as a Spring Bean. 
My working implementation adds the listener to the servlet contexts in BootStrap.groovy

```
def init = { servletContext ->
      servletContext.addListener(userLoginSessionListener)
}
```

but this causes my integration tests to fail with an UnsupportedOperationException (will create another question for this)

Now I have the following in resources.groovy

```
userLoginSessionListener(UserLoginSessionListener)
```

but now my sessionCreated and sessionDestroyed methods are no longer being triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to go down the old fashioned route. 
Removed the bean definition and BootStrap.groovy config and added the listener via the eventWebXmlEnd handler in _Events.groovy which played well with our integration tests.

```
<listener>
       <listener-class>com.example.UserLoginSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```