# Grails - UnsupportedOperationException - Integration tests

Tags: session, grails, listener, integration-testing

I have implemented a simple session listener in my Grails application but it is causing my integration tests to fail with the following:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>         at org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext.addListener(MockServletContext.java:675)
>         at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:44)
>         at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:327)

This is because the MockServletContext used for the tests does not support this listener I am adding in Bootstrap.groovy in the following line:

```
def init = { 
  servletContext ->
       servletContext.addListener(userLoginSessionListener) 
   ....

}
```

but is there a way of ignoring this or annotating my tests to not require it.

Comment: I do not have an answer to this particular issue but figured out a workaround which I have answered my other question with here -  http://stackoverflow.com/a/36886996/2288004.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be the most obvious of fixes, simply exclude adding the listener for the test environment.

```
if (Environment.current != Environment.TEST) {    
    servletContext.addListener(UserLoginSessionListener)    
}
```